# Данные из POST формы не передаются обработчику

Tags: javascript, php, html

Прошу помочь советом.

Логика формы следующая: есть список полей, некоторые из них заблокированы, некоторые - активны для ввода. Пользователь вводит ИНН контрагента, через api dadata подгружаются статистические реквизиты и записываются в value заблокированных полей. Оставшиеся поля пользователь заполняет и отправляет на сервер.

Проблема: записанные через js значения в заблокированные поля - не передаются на сервер.

```
<form action="ссылка на обработчик" method="post">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="inn">Введите ИНН контрагента</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inn" id="inn" value="" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <br />
                    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick="getdetails()">ЗАПРОС В ФНС</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="kpp">КПП контрагента</label>
                    <input type="text" name="kpp" value="" id="kpp" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="fullname">Полное наименование клиента</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fullname" value="" id="fullname" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="shortname">Краткое наименование клиента</label>
                    <input type="text" name="shortname" value="" id="shortname" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="ogrn">ОГРН</label>
                    <input type="text" name="ogrn" value="" id="ogrn" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="okpo">ОКПО</label>
                    <input type="text" name="okpo" value="" id="okpo" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="yur">Юридический адрес</label>
                    <input type="text" name="yur" value="" id="yur" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="fact">Фактический адрес</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fact" id="fact" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="director">Генеральный директор (или подписант)</label>
                    <input type="text" name="director" id="director" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="cause">Основание полномочий</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cause" id="cause" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="numbercontract">Номер договора</label>
                    <input type="text" name="numbercontract" id="numbercontract" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="datecontract">Дата договора</label>
                    <input type="data" name="datecontract" id="datecontract" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="msg"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

запись данных в поля формы происходит через

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getdetails(){
        var inn = $('#inn').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "handler.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {finn:inn}
        }).done(function(res)
            {
                $('#kpp').val(res[0].data.kpp)
                $('#fullname').val(res[0].data.name.full_with_opf)
                $('#shortname').val(res[0].data.name.short_with_opf)
                $('#okpo').val(res[0].data.okpo)
                $('#ogrn').val(res[0].data.ogrn)
                $('#yur').val(res[0].data.address.unrestricted_value)
                $('#fact').val(res[0].data.address.unrestricted_value)
                $('#director').val(res[0].data.management.name)
            });
        }
    </script>
```

в обработчике присвоение значений переменных происходит вот так

```
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$shortname = $_POST['shortname'];
$inn = $_POST['inn'];
$kpp = $_POST['kpp'];
$ogrn = $_POST['ogrn'];
$okpo = $_POST['okpo'];
$director = $_POST['director'];
$cause = $_POST['cause'];
$faddress = $_POST['fact'];
$yaddress = $_POST['yur'];
$ncontract = $_POST['numbercontract'];
$dcontract = $_POST['datecontract'];
```

После отправки на сервер получаю следующие сообщения

```
Notice: Undefined index: fullname и так далее
```

Comment: Данные с атрибутом disabled не отправляются.. Вы можете использовать атрибут readonly и стилями сделать его аналогичным disabled

Comment: @InDevX как всё оказалось на поверхности) земной поклон!

Comment: @InDevX подскажите пожалуйста, я хочу валидировать теперь readonly поля (на предмет того, что пользователь нажал кнопку и значение в этих полях имеется). Проверять их можно также, обращаясь через js к атрибуту value? Просто инспектор кода не отображает value у этих полей, хотя значения присвоены)

Comment: То что вы не видите в инспекторе не значит что там пусто. _Проверять их можно также, обращаясь через js к атрибуту value?_ - да

Comment: @InDevX спасибо!